# in which Ubuntu package is pgsql?

Tags: package-management, postgresql, debian

I would like to install `pgsql` without PostgreSQL. Is it possible? When I search the web, `pgsql` looks like lemmified to postgresql.

Comment: Debian is not Ubuntu and is off topic on this site. See this info https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [PGDG apt repository for Debian/Ubuntu](https://www.postgresql.org/about/news/pgdg-apt-repository-for-debianubuntu-1432/), then it is

`postgresql-client`

The same is used for standard Ubuntu repository.